# website not allowing web scraping - how to get around?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the content of this website (please see below image for reference): https://likms.assembly.go.kr/law/lawsLawtInqyDetl1010.do?genActiontypeCd=2ACT1010&genDoctreattypeCd=DOCT2041&procWorkId=&workstepId=&repFlowId=&flowId=&workId=&workSno=&nextWinWd=%27&nextWinHg=%27%27&nextWinTypeAttr=%27&nextMappingId=&nextGenActiontypeCd=&viewGb=PROM&contSid=0008&contId=1983123000000002&cachePreid=ALL&genMenuId=menu_serv_nlaw_lawt_1030&back_viewGb=PROM&back_contSid=0008&back_contId=1983123000000002&back_cachePreid=ALL

[image]

However when I run:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://likms.assembly.go.kr/law/lawsLawtInqyDetl1010.do?genActiontypeCd=2ACT1010&genDoctreattypeCd=DOCT2041&procWorkId=&workstepId=&repFlowId=&flowId=&workId=&workSno=&nextWinWd=%27&nextWinHg=%27%27&nextWinTypeAttr=%27&nextMappingId=&nextGenActiontypeCd=&viewGb=PROM&contSid=0008&contId=1983123000000002&cachePreid=ALL&genMenuId=menu_serv_nlaw_lawt_1030&back_viewGb=PROM&back_contSid=0008&back_contId=1983123000000002&back_cachePreid=ALL"

BeautifulSoup(get(url).text, 'html.parser').find("div", {"class:", "article"})
```

Instead of the content being scraped, I get:

```
<div class="article">
<div class="loading">
<p>로딩중 입니다.</p>
<span style="font-weight: bold;">법령정보에 대한 법적효력은 관보에 있습니다.</span><br/>
<span style="font-weight: bold;">인터넷 법령정보는 참고자료로 활용하시기 바랍니다.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

The text says something along the lines of "LOADING...the legal rights for this information is held by XXX" etc.

Does this mean I would not be able to scrape this website, or is there a way I could get around this?

Comment: Oh, no. I just wanted to make sure that the crawling is indeed blocked by the website and it is not my mistake. I'm pretty new to web-scraping so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Even if it's your mistake or not it's still illegal just to scape a website without permission. ask the website owner if it's ok to scape their website.

Answer (score 1):

Use a headless browser that will execute JavaScript and render a page (without a window). BeautifulSoup will only parse the initial HTML that's returned by the server, it doesn't execute any JavaScript.

Check out: https://www.toptal.com/python/web-scraping-with-python

Comment: Thank you! Would I be correct in thinking that this website is indeed scrapable utilising the method you kindly suggested? Or is there still a possibility that scraping may have been blocked by the website?

Comment: The website may have other types of bot protection against things like automated form submissions but if you're only scraping data and not submitting any forms I'd be surprised if there's anything that prevents you from doing so using a headless browser.

Comment: My brother worked for a bigger company with a lot of data they didn't want to be scraped. They set up high sophisticated tools to identify bots and fed them wrong information. So be aware: even if it seems to work, you might not get the correct result.